# Bootstrap 2.3.2 ".hide" class is breaking modal-body in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, joomla3.0, bootstrap-modal, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have an `<iframe>` in the modal-body of a bootstrap modal window. A Google Map will display in an `<iframe>` but not an external "scheduler" website that uses facebook markup. It displays correctly in all modern browsers, except Firefox.

If I remove the `.hide` class from the parent div, it works. HOWEVER, removing the `.hide` class causes the invisible modal to hide  elements on the page.

Is there a workaround for getting this bootstrap `.hide` class to cooperate in this scenario OR is there an appropriate fallback?

```
<div id="modal01" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Scheduling Options</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">{loadposition schedule-wrapper}</div>
    <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-blue" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you are using this code on template that uses BS3. DO you test it with Protostar or other template?

Comment: @SergeyRomanov It was a template I made from scratch, but I believe the issue lied in using https in an iframe on a non-https site. Thanks for the response, don't know why I didn't get a notify that you commented.